# Validate multiple values

Tags: jquery

What is the most simple way to check if an option value is equal to any one of multiple values?

This works but only allows to check one value.

```
if ($(this).val() == 'QA') {
   //do something
}
```

I want to check multiple values.

```
if ($(this).val() == 'QA, Efficiency, Legal, Time, BadDebt, WriteOff, BusinessInterruption') {
   //do something
}
```

I suppose I could do this but it seems like too much code?

```
if ($(this).val() == 'QA' || $(this).val() == 'Efficiency') {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$.inArray()`:

```
var valuesArray = ['QA', 'Efficiency', 'Legal', 'Time', 'BadDebt', 'WriteOff','BusinessInterruption'];

if ($.inArry($(this).val(),valuesArray) !== -1) {
    // value is present
}
```

Or, in browsers that support `Array.indexOf()`:

```
if (valuesArray.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1) {
    // value is present
}
```

You could also use a simple switch:

```
switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'QA':
    case 'Efficiency':
    case 'Legal':
    case 'Time':
    case 'BadDebt':
    case 'WriteOff':
    case 'BusinessInterruption':
         /* switches continue with all subsequent comparisons until they reach
            a `break`, so this function 'doStuff()' will be executed if *any*
            of the above match */
        doStuff();
    break;
    default:
        noneOfTheAboveMatched();
        break;
}
```

References:

- [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [JavaScript `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).
- [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: Watch out for 0 being treated as false.

Comment: Show me a ([simple/sscce](http://sscce.org/)) JS Fiddle showing what you're trying to do, and I'll see if I can help.